# Magento 2 foreign key constraint error

Tags: magento2

I've got this error when run "bin/magento setup:upgrade".

```
Module 'Magento_Catalog':
Running schema recurring...

  [PDOException]                                                                                        
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1826 Duplicate foreign key constraint name 'mydb/CAT_CTGR_PRD_CTGR_ID_CAT_CTGR_ENTT_ENTT_ID'
```

What can cause it?

Answer (score 14):

Run command:

```
php bin/magento setup:db-declaration:generate-whitelist
```

Comment: Error: Magento was installed with a table prefix. Please re-install without prefix.

Comment: Thanks @Nguyen it saves a lot of my times. Thumbs up

Answer (score 7):

just run below command if your magento version Magento 2.3 or Magento 2.4

```
php bin/magento setup:db-declaration:generate-whitelist --module-name=Vendor_Module
```

above is for generate whitelist  for perticular module or run below for all modules

```
run command: php bin/magento setup:db-declaration:generate-whitelist
```

hope this helps you :)

Comment: Error: Magento was installed with a table prefix. Please re-install without prefix.

Comment: According to Magento docs,

``Whitelists cannot be generated on Magento instances that use a database prefix. The presence of a prefix impacts the names of some DB entities, such as the names of keys, and these names cannot be used in generated whitelists. The whitelist should be generated by the extension developer on a development environment with no prefixes.``

Comment: I thought that after running this and then setup:upgrade, it was going to fail again, as it was taking such a long time to complete, and is usually much quicker. But nope, just give it time, be patient, and it will eventually complete.

Comment: Check in logs..seems its something different issue

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem on a custom table. After creation I needed to add new columns to this table.

To make such a change to the table in declarative mode I needed to generate the db_schema_whitelist.json.

Run the following command:

```
bin/magento setup:db-declaration:generate-whitelist --module-name=Your_Module
```

You can learn more about declarative schema at:
[Configure declarative schema](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/declarative-schema/db-schema.html)

Answer (score 1):

Same issue there, it seems that my columns declaration don't match (between the reference table and the table owning the foreign key), for example: one is unsigned and not the other, or one is nullable or not the other.

I didn't find a way to solve it yet, except by making these columns match (which is not what I want, for example to have a nullable foreign key).

What I don't understand is that Magento's core succeed in doing this, cf. tables `store` and `customer_entity`, where `store_id` column is nullable.

[Edit] It seems that generating a `db_schema_whitelist.json` with command `bin/magento setup:db-declaration:generate-whitelist --module-name=My_Module` solved it, didn't exactly understood why, if anyone has an explanation I would be grateful!

Comment: Too bad I cannot confirm if this worked for me or not.

Answer (score 0):

**In Magento 2.3 :**

The <module_vendor>/<module_name>/etc/db_schema_whitelist.json file provides a history of all tables, columns, and keys added with declarative schema. It is required to allow drop operations. It can be generated manually or created automatically with the following command:

bin/magento setup:db-declaration:generate-whitelist [options]
[options] can be:

--module-name[=MODULE-NAME] specifies which module to generate a whitelist for. If no module name is specified, then the default behavior is to generate a whitelist for all modules. You can also explicitly set --module-name=all.

When creating a new table, remember to generate the db_schema_whitelist.json file.

As a best practice, you should generate a new whitelist file for each release. You must generate the whitelist in any release that contains changes in the db_schema.xml file.

For more detail refer below link:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/declarative-schema/migration-commands.html#create-whitelist

For specific Module execute below command:

```
sudo php bin/magento setup:db-declaration:generate-whitelist --module-name=PackageName_ModuleName
```

Answer (score 0):

I had faced with this issue in php bin/magento setup:upgrade

`SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1826 Duplicate foreign key constraint name 'FK_8DFA69E89F93F6B2F7D11FEB4972429A', query was: ALTER TABLE` amasty_mostviewed_pack_product`MODIFY COLUMN`entity_id`int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL  AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT "Entity ID", MODIFY COLUMN`pack_id`int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0  COMMENT "Pack id", MODIFY COLUMN`product_id`int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0  COMMENT "product id", ADD CONSTRAINT`AMASTY_MOSTVIEWED_PACK_PRD_PRD_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID `FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES` catalog_product_entity `(`entity_id`)  ON DELETE CASCADE, ADD CONSTRAINT` FK_8DFA69E89F93F6B2F7D11FEB4972429A `FOREIGN KEY (`pack_id`) REFERENCES` amasty_mostviewed_pack `(`pack_id`)  ON DELETE CASCADE`

So I run

php bin/magento setup:db-declaration:generate-whitelist --module-name=Amasty_Mostviewed

this issue has been fixed